# JavaScript replace() method replaces wrong characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I am sort of new to programming and I am looking into codewars for practicing. So there is a task where you need to take a given string and turn only one letter uppercase and do that for every letter and make an array out of it. Like a Mexican wave (that is actually the name of the task).

Like this:

if a string is 'marko', array should look like `['Marko', 'mArko', 'maRko', 'marKo', 'markO']`.

All is fine until there are 2 or more of the same characters. For example if a string is 'aaa', the array is `['Aaa', 'Aaa', 'Aaa']`. It always replaces the first character of that kind.

Here is my code:

```
function wave(string){
  let result = [];
  let lowerCase = string.toLowerCase();
  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(lowerCase[i] != ' '){
     result.push(lowerCase.replace(lowerCase[i], lowerCase.charAt(i).toUpperCase()));
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Call the function with a string with unique characters like 'abc def' and it will work. After that call it with repeating characters like 'abc abc' and the problem will occur.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lowerCase.replace(lowerCase[i], lowerCase.charAt(i).toUpperCase())` will always replace the [first occurrency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) of the character `a` that's why you get the same output.

you just need to implement a way to replace the right occurrency

```js
function wave(string){
  let result = [];
  let lowerCase = string.toLowerCase();
  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(lowerCase[i] !== ' '){
     const arr = lowerCase.split(""); //create an array from the string
     arr[i] = lowerCase.charAt(i).toUpperCase(); //change the right occurency
     result.push(arr.join("")); //transform the array to a string
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(wave("aAa"));
```

Comment: Thanks Karim. Could you explain why it always replaces first instance of a character  instead of charAt(i) and please tell me how to set this to an accepted answer? I'm super new here.

Comment: hi, check the documentation, it explains you how the method work, and there's should be a button to set the accepted answer :)
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

```
function wave(string){
  let result = [];
  let lowerCase = string.toLowerCase();
  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    let item = lowerCase.slice(0,i) + lowerCase.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + lowerCase.slice(i+1);
    result.push(item);
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you want to handle some space character or things like that, it would be very simple to deduplicate the final result.

Answer (score 0):

If the `pattern` (first parameter) of the `String.prototype.replace()` method is a string, then only the first occurrence will be replaced.

With `lowerCase.replace(lowerCase[i], lowerCase.charAt(i).toUpperCase())` you just replace the first occurrence.

You can find more information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for - an explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `replaceAt` function to replace the character at a specific point in the string.

```js
function replaceAt(string, char, index) {
  return string.substr(0, index) + char + string.substr(index + 1);
}

function wave(string) {
  string = string.toLowerCase();

  return string.split('').map((char, index) => replaceAt(string, char.toUpperCase(), index));
}

const result = wave("MARKO"); // ["Marko", "mArko", "maRko", "marKo", "markO"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [String.prototype.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to split the substring at the specified index per iteration and replace the current index character to uppercase.

```js
const str = 'aaa';
const wave = function *(str) {
 for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  yield str.substring(0, i) 
                      + str.charAt(i).toUpperCase() 
                      + str.substring(i + 1);
 }
};

const res = [...wave(str)];
console.log(res);
```